# Implementing a suggestion box in SSRS for a parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a dropdown in SSRS report which has more than 2000 values, but I want to have a suggestion box instead of dropdown. so when user enters something in that parameter box suggestions should come.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to write custom report viewer application, as far as I know vanilla SSRS viewer does not allow suggestions.